# Spring data JPA inserting null into column error even though I POST a value?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to save both child and parent entities whenever a `POST` call is made. I have an `Item` entity with a `one to one` mapping to a parent table `Attribute`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Item")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;  

  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="attr_id")
  private Attribute attribute;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  private List<ValueSet> valueSets = new ArrayList<>();

  // Other fields, getters, setters, overriding equals and hashcode using Objects.equals() and Objects.hashCode() for all the fields, helper for adding and removing ValueSet
}
```

The `Attribute` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Attribute")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attribute 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
// Other fields, getters, setters, NOT overriding equals hashCode
}
```

Whenever an `Item` gets saved I need the `Attribute` to get saved as well. I've my postman sending JSON POST data as follows:

```
{
        "attribute":{
            "id":"6"
        },
        "valueSets":[
            {
                "value":"basic"
            }
        ]
}
```

My handler looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/item")
public void postItems(@RequestBody Item item)
{
    itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

`ItemRepository` is just a one liner with `@Repository` annotation:

`public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long>`

When I try to save the `Item` I run into - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'attr_id', table 'Item'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I can't figure out why is it unable to take the `id` value of 6 that I am supplying as part of my `POST` invocation. The `id` value 6 already exists on the `Attribute` table. I have also tried making the relationship bi-directional using `mappedBy` and `CASCADE.ALL` but still get the same error.

Any thoughts/suggestions on what I'm messing/missing? Also, is there a better approach to handle nested entities? Should I try to save each of them individually? In that case can the `@RequestBody` still be the parent entity?

Answer (score 1):

I have built an example project, and try to replicate your situation, not successful. I am able to insert the "item" without any issue.

I placed the project under this repository https://github.com/hepoiko/user-5483731-1

Hope this help you to troubleshooting further or let me know If I miss anything in there.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! Let me take a look. Also, I was wondering - do I really need bi-directional relationship for saving the child entity when the parent is saved? For example, do I need `List` of `ValueSets` in the parent or are there any other ways to save it without having the `@OneToMany` relation?